# Updating a ClickOnce application

Tags: winforms, deployment, clickonce, publish

I've got a ClickOnce Windows Forms application. Today I've published a new version.

The application is available offline as well.

In the Publish menu in Updates, I set:

- The application should check for updates: CHECKED
- Before application starts
- And I've specified a minimum required version for this application, equal to the new version (1.2.0.5).

When the user opens the page with the update he must refresh the page to see that the version is 1.2.0.5 (a second ago, he was seeing that it was 1.2.0.4).

When he clicks install and download setup and double clicks at his computer, the old version runs.

He unistalls old version, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Please clarify.  Your user has uninstalled the old version, goes to your installation page.  Has refreshed and verified that the publish page states that he should be downloading the 1.2.0.5 version, however, once he clicks Install, version 1.2.0.4 is installed, instead?

Comment: and there is next problem at another computer- user connect to intranet by vpn and when he refreshes page he still sees 1.2.0.4 :/

Comment: This may sound like an odd request but if you can restart the server that hosts the ClickOnce application, give that a try.  I'm a bit stumped why your users would refresh your publication page and continue to get the old web page.  My educated guess would be that some how these files are stored in a cache either on the user's PC or on the hosting server.   Technically, the server cache shouldn't behave this way but I have seen "stranger" things happen.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure if you got this problem sorted but I had a problem with ClickOnce about a year and a half ago. There are some comments in the thread below that may be of help to you, stuff about location of files when a new version is installed. You do know that when a new version of the app is available the whole app is set up in a new directory structure? Sounds like users are still pointing to the older version somehow. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263014/sql-compact-error-unable-to-load-dll-sqlceme35-dll-the-specified-module-could](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263014/sql-com

Answer (score 0):

Check the deployment manifest in the top folder of the deployment folders on the server and see what version it is actually pointing to. This is the .application file. It could be that for some reason it didn't get updated. This file defines which version the user gets when he installs the application or picks up an update.

Comment: At server I see in manifest with new version. It looks ok. I have again this problem, after I set version as 1.3.0.1 . Tomorrow people go to work, and it would me disaster :/

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be wrong in your ClickOnce updates configurations.

> In Project Settings on the Publish Tab, did you put a value in for
>   Installation Folder URL? If so, you need to make sure that you click
>   the Updates button and put the same URL in the Update location box on
>   the Application Updates screen. Also, make sure you have the The
>   application should check for updates box checked on that screen.

Look at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ClickOnceContentExpiratn.aspx) whether it helpful at all.

Look at here and check again you have set everything correctly.

[Choosing a ClickOnce Update Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e%28VS.80%29.aspx) 
[How to: Manage Updates for a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

> Although it is possible to require updates using the other update
>   strategies, checking Before the application starts is the only way to
>   guarantee that an older version cannot be run. When the mandatory
>   update is detected on startup, the user must either accept the update
>   or close the application.
>
> To mark an update as required, click Specify a minimum required
>   version for this application in the Application Updates dialog box,
>   then specify the publish version (Major, Minor, Build, Revision),
>   which specifies the lowest version number of the application that can
>   be installed. For more information, see [Application Updates Dialog
>   Box.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axw1fa38%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)